# Concatenating two columns together in R with NAs

Tags: r

I want to create a column (outcome) that would be a concatenation of two other columns.

```
col1 col2     Outcome
A     NA       A
A     B        AB
NA    NA       NA
NA    B        B
A     B        AB
```

I tried:

```
df$Outcome = c(df$col1, df$col2)
```

But it does not work. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    unite(Outcome, col1, col2, sep="", na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>%
    select(names(df), Outcome) %>%
    mutate(Outcome = na_if(Outcome, ""))
```

-output

```
#   col1 col2 Outcome
#1    A <NA>       A
#2    A    B      AB
#3 <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#4 <NA>    B       B
#5    A    B      AB
```

---

Or in `base R` in a single line

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse=""))
```

Or it can be done in a hacky way by removing the `NA` (but it may fail)

```
na_if(gsub("NA", "", do.call(paste0, df)), "")
```

---

`c` is for concatenating.  If we do the `c` on two `vector`s, the second `vector` is concatenated at the end of the first and it results in `length` equal to the sum of lengths of both vectors

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("A", "A", NA, NA, "A"), col2 = c(NA, 
 "B", NA, "B", "B")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```